# How to connect the tables?

Tags: sql-server

I want 3 table into my localdatabase.It will a personal finance program. I don't know how i connect these. 
I got an error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__outflowCash__userID__2739D489 My code is here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user] (
    [ID]      INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name] VARCHAR (25)  NOT NULL,
    [email]   VARCHAR (40)  NOT NULL,
    [password]  VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inflowCash] (
    [ID]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [category]  VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [amount]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [date]      DATE          NOT NULL,
    [comment] VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [userID]         INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([userID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[outflowCash] (
    [ID]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [category]  VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [amount]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [date]      DATE          NOT NULL,
    [comment] VARCHAR (255) NULL,
    [userID]         INT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([userID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Hi i think your’re missing some insert script. Not the exception was you trying to insert a inflowCash with userID doesn’t exist on table user it’s the principal function off the foreign key

Comment: please show us your query

Comment: okay, i posted that. One question: my connection theory is it okay? user connect to inflow and outflowcash, but i want calculate with inflow and outflow, so i will connect these too? or how?

Answer (score 0):

my query:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|database.mdf;");
conn.Open();

int id;

var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT  ID,  FROM user WHERE email = '{textboxEmail.Text}'", conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
 id = (int)reader[0];
}

conn.Close();

conn.Open()
int amount = int.Parse(textboxbAmount.Text);

var cmd2 = "INSERT INTO outflowCash(category, amount, date, comment, userID) VALUES" +
$"('{comboboxCategory.selectedValue}', '{amount}','{datetimpickerDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}', +
$" ('{textboxComment.Text}', '{id}');";

 var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
 adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd2, conn);
 adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you insert into `outflowCash` the `userID` values must point to a valid `id` value in your `user` table because you have a "foreign key" reference specified on the `outflowCash` table.

Comment: thank you! i found the problem, i dont said pass "id" value from a LoginForm to a MainForm. I maked a mistake with it...